# Sum of list values in a df, new column, values are objects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a df made of values from a dictionary. I can get rid of [], ',' and split it all in different cols (one col per number). But can't make the transfer to float, tried different ways. I'm looking for new cols with sum of values for each []. Used (df1['all'][0]) and got the numbers like in column 'all'.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'all':['[0.75, 0.34, 0.91, 0.12, 0.5],[0.54, 0.65, 0.5, 0.79, 0.91],[0.81, 0.77, 0.82, 0.66, 0.38],[0.0, 0.78, 0.87, 0.81, 0.67],[0.0, 0.0, 0.56, 0.44, 0.0]']
        }
 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
print(df1)
```

Preferred output

```
    all                all1    all2   all3    all4    all5
0  [0.75, 0.34.....    2.62    3.39   3.44    3.13    1.0
```

Comment: could you include your desired output?

Comment: should be there....

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"all": orig} | {f"all{i}": sum(l) for i, l in enumerate(row, 1)}
        for orig, row in zip(df1["all"], df1["all"].apply(literal_eval))
    ]
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                                                                                    all  all1  all2  all3  all4  all5
0  [0.75, 0.34, 0.91, 0.12, 0.5],[0.54, 0.65, 0.5, 0.79, 0.91],[0.81, 0.77, 0.82, 0.66, 0.38],[0.0, 0.78, 0.87, 0.81, 0.67],[0.0, 0.0, 0.56, 0.44, 0.0]  2.62  3.39  3.44  3.13   1.0
```

Comment: fyi ... requires Python 3.9+ for the dictionary merge operator '|' to work.

Comment: 3.9 is the limit - working with anaconda/ jupyter

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of @Andrej Kesely answer.  This modification works for Python <3.9 and does not drop other columns that are contained in df1.

```
from ast import literal_eval 

df_out = pd.concat(
    [
        df1,
        pd.DataFrame(
            [
                {**{f"all{i}": sum(l) for i, l in enumerate(row, 1)}}
                for row in df1["all"].apply(literal_eval)
            ]
        )
    ],
    axis=1        
)
print(df_out)

  col1 col2                                                all  all1  all2  all3  all4  all5 
0    A    C  [0.75, 0.34, 0.91, 0.12, 0.5],[0.54, 0.65, 0.5...  2.62  3.39  3.44  3.13   1.0 
1    B    D  [0.75, 0.34, 0.91, 0.12, 0.5],[0.54, 0.65, 0.5...  2.62  3.39  3.44  3.13   1.0
```

Comment: works fine, how to make it work for all other rows of df? I get only one row, as I wrote , others with NaN, but df has more rows.

Comment: Works. I had cols before all in original df, which dissappear now.  I used merged now to combine. Any smart, simple solution in the code you wrote, I can use?